# UITableView initiate row rearrange without using edit button

Tags: uitableview, ios5

Basically, I intend on using a long-press to initiate row rearranges.  Is this possible with UITableView?  I can't seem to find a method in UITableView to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard UITableViewController does not support what you'd like to do unfortunately. However, [ReorderingTableViewController by Daniel Shusta](https://github.com/shusta/ReorderingTableViewController) does - check it out.

Comment: Well, the answer came a little late for me.  I actually ended up subclassing UITableView and implementing my own long-press Reordering method(s).  To bad I never found this solution though, it was quite a bit of work for me. My only complaint about this solution is that it updates the datasource on each row change as you move, whereas I needed it to update the datasource only when the cell is 'dropped'.  But it's a great solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your long press handler you can programmatically set the editing mode on the **UITableView** with this method:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate
```

And then you have to implement two methods from the **UITableViewDatasource** protocol:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
  return YES; 
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
{
 ...
}
```

So the **UITableView** knows that the reordering mode must be enabled.

[UITableView reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[UITableViewDatasource reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: No, that doesn't work.  I mean, it puts the tableview into editing mode, but that's not what I want.  What I want is the 'mode'/whatever tableview is in when the cell is following the user's finger.  Essentially, I want the user to be able to rearrange the table by long-pressing, and then dragging the cell.  I suspect that I'll need to write my own tableview implementation, but of course I'd rather use Apple's if I can.

Comment: If you implement the two methods from UITableViewDataSource the UITableView shows the re-arrange icons inside the cells when in editing mode, then you can long-press on a cell (or only press, I don't remember) and you can re-arrage that cell. If this is not what you want I guess you'll have to subclass UITableView and customize the behaviour.